# Slack: 3rd party account linking

Tags: oauth, access-token, slack, openid-connect

I wonder if it is possible to use account linking (like you can do e.g. with Google Actions or Amazon Alexa) with a Slack bot in order to use customer information from my ownd 3d party service/app.

One use case would be like:

- add slack bot (e.g. a game) to workspace
- trigger some action like "what is my current score?"
- prompt a dialog/flow provided by slack to authenticate against my service

  - slack app/bot is configured with according client credentials and uris for oauth/OIDC
- once successfully authenticated, handle request with access_token provided by slacks token management (automated refreshing etc.)

This is basically how it works with Google Actions and Amazon Alexa etc.

But I did not find any hints to that in the Slack docs.
And "Sign in with Slack" is actually not an option.

Any idea?

Cheers
Thomas